# Lit-Element: which event to use for DOM updates?

Tags: javascript, web-component, lit-element

The documentation over at [github.com/Polymer/lit-element](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element#advanced-update-lifecycle) describes the lifecycl, if a **property** of some lit-element is changed. However, I can not seem to find any documentation about a lifecycle if the DOM content of the element is changed.

So assume I have some nested DOM structure and my outermost element should display something based on the DOM content. For sake of simplicity the example below will just display the number of child-elements of the given type.

Now at some point my application inserts a new nested element (click the `test` button below). At this point I would like to update the shown count.

From my tests it seems that `render()` is not called again in that case, neither is `updated()`.

**Which event do I need to listen or which function do I need to implement for to recognize such a change?**

My only current workaround is to use `requestUpdate()` manually after the DOM update, but I think such changes should be handled by lit-element itself.

```js
  document.querySelector( 'button' )
          .addEventListener( 'click', () => {
            const el = document.querySelector( 'my-element' );
            el.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', '<my-nested-element>new addition</my-nested-element>' );
          })
```

```css
my-element, my-nested-element {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs@latest/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>

<!-- Works only on browsers that support Javascript modules like Chrome, Safari, Firefox 60, Edge 17 -->
<script type="module">
  import {LitElement, html} from 'https://unpkg.com/@polymer/lit-element/lit-element.js?module';

  class MyElement extends LitElement {
    constructor(){
      super();
      this.number = this.querySelectorAll( 'my-nested-element' ).length;
    }
  
    render() {
      return html`<p>number of my-nested-element: ${this.number}</p> 
                  <slot></slot>`;
    }  
  }
  customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
  
 class MyNestedElement extends LitElement {
    render() {
      return html`<slot></slot>`;
    }  
  }
  customElements.define('my-nested-element', MyNestedElement);
</script>

<my-element>
  <my-nested-element>first</my-nested-element>
  <my-nested-element>second</my-nested-element>
</my-element>

<button>test</button>
```

Comment: you could listen to the slotchange event

Comment: @Supersharp Thanks! After some fiddling with the details (seems I need to attach the event to the `shadowRoot` and not the element itself), this worked. If you put that into an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to detect a new element inserted from the Light DOM through a `<slot>` element, you can listen to [slotchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/slotchange) events on the `<slot>` element, or on the Shadow DOM root itself.

See the running example below:

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => 
  document.querySelector('my-element').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<my-nested-element>new addition</my-nested-element>');
```

```css
my-element,
my-nested-element {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
  import {LitElement, html} from 'https://unpkg.com/@polymer/lit-element/lit-element.js?module';

  class MyElement extends LitElement {
    firstUpdated() {
      var shadow = this.shadowRoot
      var nb = shadow.querySelector( 'span#nb' )
      shadow.addEventListener( 'slotchange', () => 
        nb.textContent = this.querySelectorAll( 'my-nested-element').length 
      )    
    }
    render() {
      return html`<p>number of my-nested-element: <span id="nb"></span></p> 
                  <slot></slot>`;
    }  
  }
  customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
</script>

<my-element>
  <my-nested-element>first</my-nested-element>
  <my-nested-element>second</my-nested-element>
</my-element>

<button>test</button>
```